# Game theory - How was the table of decision analysis formulation constructed?

Tags: proof-explanation, game-theory, operations-research, decision-theory

Could someone please explain how the table in the solution was constructed?

Particularly in the first row, why $0$ and why $54$ millions?

Why was $6$ and $600$ millions not included ?

[image]

Solution

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $6$ was included.  If the company sells $10,000$ with a variable profit of $600$ each they make $6$ million, but the fixed cost is $6$ million, so the profit is $0$.  If they sell $100,000$, the variable profit is $60$ million.  Deducting the $6$ million fixed cost leaves $54$ million.

Comment: got it, thank you.